# % of MAX but if MAX, % of 2nd MAX

Tags: excel, max

Pretend I have data of 10 football player names (column A) and their average punt length (column B).

I'm trying to find a formula I can use on excel where it will give me the % of the MAX for each punter AND also the % of the 2nd place for the punter with the longest average punter. I can get the % of MAX for all 10 punters but currently the player with the longest punt average has 100%.

If the player with the longest punt has 40 yards and the player with the second longest punt has 30 yards, I should get a % of 133% but currently I'm getting 100% because I'm using B1/(MAX(B1:B10). Please help! Thank you :)

Comment: Some  additional details would be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do :

`=B1/LARGE($B$1:$B$10, 1+(B1=MAX($B$1:$B$10)))`

Comment: Glad to help. If you accept my answer by ticking it, we both earn a few points here :-)

Answer (score 0):

This formula should work for you.

=`B1/LARGE($B$1:$B$10,2)`

Just copy it for all the required cells

The result should look like this.
[image]